About warning while using the HAL_UART_Transmit
I got warning while using this HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2,"AT\n\r",strlen(ATcommand),1000);
line of code, I am using stm32f412zgt6 controller with stm32 cubeide
I wants to overcome from the existing warning if anyone know the reason please make it to my notification and if anyone know whether stm32 or esp32 is good for real time application please make it to my notification

Please [edit] your question to include your actual code (formatted in a code block), and the exact warning that your compiler is giving you. One thing I can see already is that you are passing the length of what is possibly a different string than the string you send.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Try to add a typecasting before your command, it will fix USART warnings
Your Implementation:
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2,"AT\n\r",strlen(ATcommand),1000);

Correct Implementation:
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2,(uint8_t*)"AT\n\r",strlen(ATcommand),1000);

